# Adding a hyperlink into a PHP search script that is echo'ing results

Tags: php

I have the below search script, and I need to have the COMPANY section of the results link to each companies website (stored in column WEBSITE in my database). Can anyone help?

```
if(isset($_POST['completedsearch'])) {
    $term = $_POST['query'];
    $mysql = mysql_connect("ldb504.securepod.com","martindb","green11");
    mysql_select_db("hcsd");
    $qu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Sheet1 WHERE COMPANY LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($term)."%' OR LOCATION LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($term)."%' OR KEYWORDS LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($term)."%' OR PRODUCTSSERVICES LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($term)."%' "); //selects the row that contains ANYTHING like the submitted string
    echo "Searching for '$term'";
    echo "
        <table><tr style=\"border-bottom:1px dotted #305896;\"><th style=\"padding:0px 10px;text-align:left;border-bottom:1px dotted #305896;\">Company</th>
        <th style=\"padding:0px 10px;text-align:left;border-bottom:1px dotted #305896;\">Location</th>
        <th style=\"padding:0px 10px;text-align:left;border-bottom:1px dotted #305896;\">Products/Services</th></tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qu)) {
        echo"<tr style=\"border-bottom:1px dotted #305896;\"><td style=\"padding:0px 10px;text-align:left;border-bottom:1px dotted #305896;\">";  
        echo"<a href="'.urlencode($row['WEBSITE']).'">'.htmlspecialchars($row['COMPANY']).'</a>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td style=\"padding:0px 10px;text-align:left;border-bottom:1px dotted #305896;\">";
        echo htmlspecialchars($row['LOCATION']);
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td style=\"padding:0px 10px;text-align:left;border-bottom:1px dotted #305896;\">";
        echo htmlspecialchars($row['PRODUCTSSERVICES']);
        echo "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: What kind of help do you need? If you have the company URL, make the company name into a link-- what's keeping you?

Comment: @alexis see my comment on the answer below.

Comment: Glad someone was able to help you! That doesn't make it a good question, though: In the future, be specific about the problem and the chances of getting help will be much higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your php mixing the single and double quotes:

```
echo"<a href="'.urlencode($row['WEBSITE']).'">'.htmlspecialchars($row['COMPANY']).'</a>";
```

Should be something like:

```
echo '<a href="'.urlencode($row['WEBSITE']).'">'.htmlspecialchars($row['COMPANY']).'</a>';
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this has worked, I'll accept your answer in 7minutes when it lets me.. lol EDIT: for some reason the link is showing as "http://www.healthcareservicesdirect.com/http://www.sky.com", any ideas on what's wrong?

Comment: @user2965329 What do `$row['WEBSITE']` and `$row['COMPANY']` contain exactly, can you add a `var_dump` to the question?

Comment: $row['COMPANY'] contains the company name $row['WEBSITE'] contains the URL of said company, eg. Sky & http://www.sky.com/ OR Virgin Media & http://www.virginmedia.com/   ETA I'm new to PHP so I'm not sure what you mean by var_dump

Comment: @user2965329 You should add `var_dump($row['WEBSITE']);`, etc. (including the whole built string) to see what it contains exactly.

Comment: so I'd add var_dump($row['WEBSITE']) inside the urlencode brackets?

Comment: @user2965329 No, somewhere outside the table, it is just to check the values of the variables.